# The Chimera tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

So someone edited the [chimera](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera) tag recently and I noticed that it said it was a human animal hybrid. This is not what a chimera is. A chimera is a mix of, if I remember right, 3 creatures each with heads, goat, dragon, and lion, and is a specific creature.

Chimeras beyond that are not "human hybrids" they are other animal hybrids in mythology, each with features that can be seen from the respective animal. Humans aren't considered animals and so would never be mixed in as a chimera in mythology.

Medically a chimera is anything that naturally has parts that from a different genetic thing. For example, most women are chimeras, shown by having splotchy skin patches where the other person's(?) genetic cells are seen. Female calico cats are chimera, their 3 fur colors owing to the fact that 1 of the fur colors belongs to cells from a genetically different cat.

The only time when the term "chimera" is used to mean human-animal hybrid that I am aware of is in Full Metal Alchemist. That being the case, i don't think that the tag should specify human-animal hybrids (or include them at all). Or there needs to be different tags for these things... or something cuz there are 4 things that chimera refers to, the least accurate 1 being used with the tag.

Comment: Hmm, there doesn’t seem to be a [tag:chimera] tag!

Comment: What is the difference between chimera-folk and were-creatures?

Comment: were-creatures are those that are human or whatever and turn into whatever or human where as chimera-folk only have one form. Also "were-creature" is not the proper term... It's something-thrope, not lycanthrope, that is specifically a wolf type. Also some lycanthropes, that don't transform but have a hybrid look, are chimera, not were

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, the Chimera isn't a specific creature except when it's specifically referenced in Greek mythology:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology))

> The term chimera has come to describe any mythical or fictional animal with parts taken from various animals, or to describe anything composed of very disparate parts, or perceived as wildly imaginative, implausible, or dazzling.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chimera)

> 1. (often initial capital letter) a mythological, fire-breathing monster, commonly represented with a lion's head, a goat's body, and a serpent's tail.
> 2. any similarly grotesque monster having disparate parts, especially as depicted in decorative art.
> 3. a horrible or unreal creature of the imagination; a vain or idle fancy: 
>      He is far different from the chimera your fears have made of him.
> 4. Genetics. an organism composed of two or more genetically distinct tissues, as an organism that is partly male and partly female, or an artificially produced individual having tissues of several species.

And here we have a [neo-Hittite Chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(mythology)#/media/File:Museum_of_Anatolian_Civilizations080.jpg):
[image]

For a bunch of different kinds of chimera, see

[Chimeras and Chimera Mythology](http://hubpages.com/education/chimeramythology)
which lists quite a few chimeras involving bits of human (most obvious being a centaur)

However, The only tag I see being used is [chimera-folk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera-folk) which includes the word "folk", implying people.  It's also only used in four questions.

Is it really a big deal?

Comment: The list of having human bits is just wrong. Chimera was a specific thing and then got applied generally as time moved forward. Then because things like centaurs are hybrids in modern times people started adding them to the word chimera when they're not... As far as is it a big deal, yes and no... no because it's not that important, but yes because if I want to talk about "the chimera" or actual chimeras then I can't use the tag as it is, because it explicitly doesn't cover them, by saying it is specifically hybrids with humans.

Comment: In which case, you'd need to create a dedicated [tag:chimera] tag.  The current [tag:chimera-folk] (as I see it) is for Centaurs, Sphinxes, Mintoars, Medusas, , Mer-people, etc.  Since the more broad [tag:chimera-folk] tag has only four questions, it seems unlikely there's a call for a dedicated tag for just the one creature.

Comment: I thought that the tag was chimera and not chimera-folk. I guess that's what you get when you look at this stuff when you first wake up. ^.^ Though that there are only 4 questions that use the tag when i know there are more questions that talk about those creatures indicate that that tag is pretty useless or unknown.

Comment: Yeah, it takes me a few coffees to wake up after getting into work at 7am...  I ran a very quick question search for "chimera" and most of the ones I saw related to hybrids rather than your classical Greek creature.  Then again, I don't think that the chimera-folk is descriptive enough of a name to be obvious to people asking those kinds of questions.

Comment: If you want to rename "chimera-folk" as "chimera-like" or "chimera-in-the-biology-sense" I'd be ok with that. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chimera Definition 3: **an individual, organ, or part consisting of tissues of diverse genetic constitution; A hybrid created through fusion of a sperm and an egg from different species is a chimera.**

Comment: @srm I think that chimera-folk was intended to refer to hybrid people like me-people, centaur, miniature, etc. For that purpose, it's fine as it is, if somewhat no-intuitive. What other tag name would you use for half -man /half -beast?

Comment: @Pete I agree with the purpose. I was trying to suggest alternate names since some folks didn't seem to like the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Human animal hybrids not otherwise given their own tag use the [chimera-folk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera-folk) tag.  The wiki for [chimera](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera) then should xref that and explain that this tag for non-human animal (and other life forms) mixtures only.

I beleive I created [chimera-folk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera-folk) and cleaned up one-offs and untagged questions, a while back.  There was some discussion on which specific one to have and using the `-folk` suffix as a unifying theme.

---

Edit: I don’t see any [chimera](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chimera) tag at all!  So I’m not understanding your question. (Or has it been delted already?)

Comment: Take a look at Pete's answer's comments. I was just waking up when I saw it, and didn't realize it was "chimera-folk" rather than just "chimera"

Comment: The [tag:chimera-folk] description has  ot beed edited recently. I see no edits since I created it.

Comment: The edit was up for a vote about 7 hours ago. and currently has 2 votes on it, at least as far as i can see, and it was proposed by SRM.